# how to map array having keys and values pairs dynamically added

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Hy, My Question is how we can map an array in react js in which the array has key-value pairs but these key values are dynamically added to the array . I mean I don't know what next key-value pair would come in an array.

**example below**

```
var array = [{ name: "kamran", age: 25 }, { dev: "kamran", hellow: "kamran" }, { "unknown key will be add dynamically": "unknown value to that key will be add dynamically" }];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(tifOptions[i]);
}
```

I want to show it on the table with keys and values using the map function. but the situation is data is coming from a rest API every time it gives me a different array of objects how could I show it will key and value I need to add to the project. because I don't know what key and value will come in the next API request

like below

first request from same API
[
{
'name':"kamran",
'age':25,
},

```
    {
      'dev':"js",
      'db':"mongo",
    },
```

];

second request from same API
[
{
'name':"kamran",
'age':25,
},

```
    {
      'dev':"js",
      'db':"mongo",
    },

    {
        'job':"student",
        "salary":20000,
    }
```

];
third request from same API
[
{
'name':"kamran",
'age':25,
},

```
    {
      'dev':"js",
      'db':"mongo",
    },

    {
        'job':"student",
        "salary":20000,
    },
    {
      ' unknown key will be added':"unknown value will be added",
      ' unknown key will be added':"unknown value will be added",
    }
```

];

and it goes on every time different key values how could I show this type of data on table with keys and value bcz I don't know in the next request what key value paire would come.

Comment: what do you mean by `map an array`? You are outputting each element already, what is the desired output?

Comment: Desired output?

Comment: I want to show it on the table with keys and values using the map function. but the situation is data is coming from a rest API every time it gives me a different array of objects how could I show it will key and value I need to add to the project. because I don't know what key and value will come in the next API request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you are going to do something with the key & value pairs coming from the API.

```
var array = [{ name: "kamran", age: 25 }, { dev: "kamran", hellow: "kamran" }, { "unknown key will be add dynamically": "unknown value to that key will be add dynamically" }];

array.map(item => {
        var keys = Object.keys(item);
        var obj= {};

        keys.forEach(key => {
          console.log("key : " ,key, "value : ", item[key])
          // do some logic here
          obj[key] = item[key];
        })

        return obj;
}))}
```

Live link here : https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-lewin-pgyu8u?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer pretty obvious if you do some googling
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

The function simply let you map a new array base on your base array no matter what element is in it

Comment: I want to show it on the table with keys and values using the map function. but the situation is data is coming from a rest API every time it gives me a different array of objects how could I show it will key and value I need to add to the project. because I don't know what key and value will come in the next API request.